# How to get today's all orders by restaurant in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to get today's orders by a restaurant. Here is my table structure

```
      restaurants
            id - integer
            name - string

        categories
            id - integer
            restaurant_id- foreign
            name - string

        items
            id - integer
            category_id - foreign
            name - string

        orders
            id - integer
            amonut- double

        order_items (pivot table)
            id - integer
            order_id - foreign
            item_id - foreign
```

Here is my restaurant model

```
public function restaurant_categories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'restaurant_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}

public function restaurant_items() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Item::class, Category::class, 'restaurant_id', 'category_id')->with('category', 'item_assets')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

Here is my Item model

```
  public function orders(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class,'order_items','item_id', 'order_id' )
    ->withPivot('quantity','price');
 }
```

By this code, I get specific restaurant's all orders

```
 $restaurant = Restaurant::with('restaurant_items')->find($id);
 $orders = [];
 foreach ($restaurant->restaurant_items as $item) {
    $orders[] = $item->orders;
  }
```

But now, How & where can I add where condition to get only today's order? and also if I want to get specific date's orders then what to do?L

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.6+ version, you can just have to add whereDate() condition

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::with('restaurant_items')
     ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

Or you can also use whereRaw()

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::with('restaurant_items')
    ->whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->get();
```